# Alterar placeholder verificando radio com jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Olá, estou tentando alterar o placeholder de um input fazendo a verificação entre 2 valores de input radio.
Segue abaixo o js que tentei montar e o html.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#tipousuario').prop('checked',function () {                    
  if($(this).val() === '1'){
   $(this).attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CNPJ",maxlenght:"14"});
  }
  if($(this).val() ==='2'){
   $(this).attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CRC",maxlenght:"8"});
  }
 });
});
```

```html
 <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser" id="tipousuario" value="1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">CNPJ</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser" id="tipousuario" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">CRC</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                                   
        <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" maxlength="14" name="usuario" id="InputUsuario" pattern="[0-9]+$" placeholder="Usuário">                                    
        <small class="text-muted">Apenas números</small>
   </div>
```

Comment: Olá Rafael! Até hoje vc não marcou uma resposta com ✓. É importante pra comunidade que as perguntas sejam finalizadas, e para isso é preciso marcar uma resposta. Se nenhuma lhe atendeu, vc pode fazer questionamentos aos AR (autor da resposta), mas não deixe perguntas em aberto pq isso prejudica o propósito do site. ObG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua lógica faz sentido, mas existem algumas falha em seu código, vamos lá:

1. Na linha `$('#tipousuario').prop('checked',` na verdade precisa aplicar o evento ao elemento para capturar quando o valor for alterado, então alteramos para: `$('.tipousuario').on('change',`;
2. Na linha `$('#tipousuario')`, como são 2 radio, fazendo a busca por ID só podemos pegar 1 elemento, pois por definição cada documento HTML não deve ter elementos com ID duplicados, então renomeei os ID's para tornarem-se únicos e acrescentei a classe tipousuario
3. Na linha `$(this).attr({`, precisamos na verdade alterar os atributos no input text, então alteramos para selecionar pelo ID do input: `$('#InputUsuario')`

Segue abaixo com os ajustes:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.tipousuario').on('change',function () {
  if($(this).val() === '1'){
   $('#InputUsuario').attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CNPJ",maxlength :"14"});
  }
  if($(this).val() ==='2'){
   $('#InputUsuario').attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CRC",maxlength :"8"});
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input tipousuario" type="radio" name="tipouser" id="tipousuario1" value="1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">CNPJ</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input tipousuario" type="radio" name="tipouser" id="tipousuario2" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">CRC</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                                   
        <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" maxlength="14" name="usuario" id="InputUsuario" pattern="[0-9]+$" placeholder="Insira seu CNPJ">                                    
        <small class="text-muted">Apenas números</small>
   </div>
```

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta +1

Comment: Realmente não prestei atenção à esses detalhes simples. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro de tudo você não pode colocar o mesmo id para dois elementos diferentes, então eu o removi do elemento `radio`, e utilizei o `name` para manipular.

Acrescentei o evento `change`, para poder pegar a mudança de estados do elemento `radio`.

Inicializei o `placeholder` com `Insira seu CNPJ`.

E removi o `$(this)` na parte onde é enviado os valor, isso faz com que seja alterado os atributos do `radio` e não do `input`.

**Resultado:**

**html**(Só removi os ids repetido)

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser" value="1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">CNPJ</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">CRC</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                                   
        <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" maxlength="14" name="usuario" id="InputUsuario" pattern="[0-9]+$" placeholder="Usuário">                                    
        <small class="text-muted">Apenas números</small>
   </div>
```

**Código jquery:**

```
$(function () {
    var usuario = $('[name="usuario"]');
  var tipouser = $('[name="tipouser"]');
  usuario.attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CNPJ",maxlength:"14"});
    tipouser.change(function () {                    
        if($(this).val() === '1'){
            usuario.attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CNPJ",maxlength:"14"});
        }
        if($(this).val() ==='2'){
            usuario.attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CRC",maxlength:"8"});
        }
    });
});
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/bucnocqs/9/

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer usando [ternário](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx), pegando click nos `radios buttons` pelo `name="tipouser"`.

> Além do erro em `id`s duplicados, havia outro erro: em vez de
>   `maxlength` você estava usando `maxlenght` (terminando com `ht`).

**Código:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('[name="tipouser"]').click(function() {
      $('#InputUsuario').attr(
         $(this).val() === '1' ? // operador ternário
         { placeholder:"Insira seu CNPJ", maxlength:"14" } : // aqui se o valor for igual a 1
         { placeholder:"Insira seu CRC", maxlength:"8" } // aqui se o valor não for 1
      );
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-7">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser" id="tipousuario1" value="1" checked>
         <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">CNPJ</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser" id="tipousuario2" value="2">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">CRC</label>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">                                   
     <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" maxlength="14" name="usuario" id="InputUsuario" pattern="[0-9]+$" placeholder="Insira seu CNPJ">                                    
     <small class="text-muted">Apenas números</small>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simplesmente genial

Comment: Vlw , fiz rápido e n me dei conta dos detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

O [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) define um identificador exclusivo (ID) que deve ser único por todo o documento, portanto você não pode repeti-lo.

Ao invés de pegar seu `input` pelo `id` eu passo a pegar ele pelo atributo `name`.

Outro ponto importante é que no seu exemplo o valor de [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) depende de como a função é chamada. Ele faz referência ao `input` alterado, ou seja, `<input type="radio" />`.

Então quando você diz:

```
$(this).attr({placeholder:"Insira seu CRC",maxlenght:"8"});
```

você está modificando os atributos do `input` errado.

Mais um ponto importante é que o nome do atributo `maxlength` estava errado.

**Sugestão:**
Limpe o valor do `input` a cada alteração pois se o máximo de caracters muda aquele valor pode não ser mais válido.

**Exemplo funcionando:**

```js
$('input[name="tipouser"]').on("change", function(){
 
 //Como sugestão eu limpo o valor do input pois se o máximo 
 //de caracters muda aquele valor pode não ser mais válido:
 $("#InputUsuario").val("");
 
 
  if($(this).val() === '1'){
    $("#InputUsuario").attr({
      placeholder:"Insira seu CNPJ",
      maxlength:14
    });
  }
  
  if($(this).val() === '2'){
    $("#InputUsuario").attr({
      placeholder:"Insira seu CRC",
      maxlength:8
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser"  value="1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">CNPJ</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipouser" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">CRC</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                                   
        <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control"  name="usuario" id="InputUsuario" pattern="[0-9]+$" maxlength="14"  placeholder="Usuário">                                    
        <small class="text-muted">Apenas números</small>
   </div>
```